# MBR getting wiped out?

Tags: windows-10, boot, bios, mbr

My windows 10 installation has started failing to boot.  All has been fine for a year or so, and then when I power the system up it boots to bios, the screen flashes black, power cycles, and then bios comes up again.

I thought that the MBR somehow got tweaked, and did some troubleshooting.  Following [these instructions](https://www.pntbrother.com/fix-bootrec-rebuildbcd-fails-the-requested-system-device-cannot-be-found-windows-10-8-7/) fixed it and all was good (or so I thought).  Rebooting worked as expected.  This morning however, the exact same thing happened again- and I had to go through that same process to get it to boot up again.

What could be going on to trash my MBR like that? Hard drive failure?  Something in the OS that's corrupting things? The drive is a SanDisk Ultra II 960GB, and my motherboard is an ASUS ROG Maximus VII Gene.  I'm also on the windows 10 insider track... maybe something there is tweaking things?

Comment: Honestly sounds like your drive could be going bad. The SanDisk tools can test the drive for you: https://kb.sandisk.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/15108/

Comment: @Unfundednut thanks, just ran that and it didn't find any problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone finding this, I never found the solution.  Tried everything I could think of.  Checked AHCI BIOS settings, and made sure Windows 10 registry settings were correct.  Deleted the MBR entirely and rebuilt from scratch.  Ran offline virus software to make sure boot record was clean.  Nothing worked.

Ended up wiping the entire drive and reinstalling everything from scratch, and all is good.  Painful.